# Elastic Search how to group by date (when nested in arrays)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have the database structured as :

```
{
    name:"string",
    ....
    arrayData: [ 
        { price:100, date: "yyyy-mm-dd" },
        { price:120, date: "yyyy-mm-dd" } ,
        { price:150, date: "yyyy-mm-dd" } ,
        { price:250, date: "yyyy-mm-dd" } 
    ]
}
```

How do I get the **average price for 2015** ?

My current approach was to aggregate the price using this filter:

```
{
  "range": {
    "arrayData.date": {
      "gte": "2015-01-01",
      "lt": "2016-01-01"
    }
  }
}
```

The test aggregation :

```
"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "arrayData.date",
        "interval": "1y",
        "time_zone": "Europe/Helsinki",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "arrayData.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But this will also get the average for the other years in the documents with a matching date in arrayData.

This is also supposed to work with Kibana, as in the end I'll have to add it to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I need to map the objects in the array as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/nested.html).

According to Elastic Documentation:

> Arrays of inner object fields do not work the way you may expect.
>   Lucene has no concept of inner objects, so Elasticsearch flattens
>   object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values. For
>   instance, the following document:
>
> ```
> {
>   "user" : [ 
>     {
>       "first" : "John",
>       "last" :  "Smith"
>     },
>     {
>       "first" : "Alice",
>       "last" :  "White"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> The user field is dynamically added as a field of type object and
>   would be transformed internally into a document that looks more like
>   this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "user.first" : [ "alice", "john" ],
>   "user.last" :  [ "smith", "white" ]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using terms Aggregration you will get your result.

```
       {
            "aggs": {
                 "date": {
                 "terms": {
                 "field": "date"
       },
           "aggs": {
                 "average": {
                 "avg": {
                 "field": "price"
                        }
                         }
                  }
                  }
                  }
                   }
```